# Is it possible to convert nerve signals or electrical pulses into a readable format?

Tags: neuroscience

Can we have the technology to recreate the informations (like images, sounds etc.)[as in the form of signals in our mind] from human mind to human understandable format? In short, can we read human mind?

Comment: Ist of all, i am posting this question again because i have asked that question but my account was not linked to it earlier, so i m unable to comment on it.

Comment: Thus i am adding all the previous comments here

Comment: The question is slightly unclear to me. Although we can measure brain electrical activity and do things like fMRI but we can't read the human mind which is why I said the question is vague since the definition of reading the human mind is required. What I essentially mean is mind is the construct of the brain and although we can measure brain activity but mind reading is not yet possible unless we can have a highly exact knowledge of the brain activity to know how it is perceived, which I do not know if we have reached that stage yet. –  Bez Aug 20 at 13:09

Comment: For clarity, Let me ask in two ways: Our Eyes sees anything (e.g. an image of a tree) then convert into a signal/electric pulses; to be processed in mind and then stored in mind. Now, 1. Do we Have the Technology or machinery to read that image before conversion? and 2. Do we Have the Technology or machinery to read the signals after conversion? –  Khushhal Aggarwal Aug 22 at 21:23

Comment: In between these 2 questions, what happens is -- "CONVERSION" of that Information. That conversion method must be a "TECHNIQUE". Thus if we are able to design a machine to convert the same information by the same "TECHNIQUE" as used by the human mind, then it will be helpful to understand the signals after conversion. In short, can we define/design the mechanism to convert the the informations into signals/electric pulses? –  Khushhal Aggarwal Aug 22 at 21:47

Comment: for 1, I would say no. For 2 I would say fMRI is addressing this and it is at its infancy but the problem is an image, which produces lets say fMRI machine data analysed/visualised by a computer, is usually associated with many things in the human brain such memory and experience and one image can provoke another depending on the individual so its not as easy as signal A equals object A. Don't know much about fMRI but it measures neuronal activity. Apologies if i cannot be of further help. –  Bez Aug 22 at 22:51

Comment: This is what researchers are trying to do with machine learning algorithms. There have been certain successes but the field is still in its infancy. Typically one tries to decode ("read the mind") between few simple classes, e.g. does the person see a happy vs. sad face. The input to the algorithm can be EEG, MEG, fMRI, etc.

See e.g. http://www.nature.com/news/brain-decoding-reading-minds-1.13989

Things like decoding content of dreams, visual imagery, or moral judgements have succeeded this far.

Comment: I think the researchers are trying to understand/develop the converted informations (i.e. signal/electric pulse) but i am asking from a different view; i am focusing on the method by which our mind converts it. I am symbolising it as "TECHNIQUE" to convert the informations into signals/electric pulses. Thus, i want to understand/define/design that "TECHNIQUE". –  Khushhal Aggarwal Aug 22 at 22:00

Comment: Mr. Bez, Ist of all Thank you for all your support and no appologies are required but please look again at the matter with a different view. I am actually trying to understand the method to convert images into signals which i think no one else has thought of. Everybody is trying to read the signals already converted and stored into our mind. But what if we developed the Technique  by which our mind converts the informations.

Comment: This is the third post that asks exactly the same question.

Comment: Dear WYSIWYG sir, This is actually the 2nd post because i posted it again due to account problems. Please do continue to answer here. And i request you to please take a look at all the comments. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question to add the details that you mention in the comments.

Comment: I will follow your suggestion in all the next questions but since i had copied this question from my older post i have to mention these comments separtely because these are the comments posted by others like Mr. Bez etc. But i sincerely thanks for this kind suggestion. Now if you can give some views on the question, i will be obliged.

Comment: Sorry Mr. Bez, I am unable to understand what you are trying to say by the comment "possible duplicate of ...".